# GUI slowness observed with Lighttpd V1.4.54 + openssl V1.1.1g

Tags: openssl, webserver, lighttpd

We are using Lighttpd V1.4.54 with OpenSSL V1.1.1g for our Access Point GUI. Observing a GUI slowness while landing on the first page(Dashboard). Enabled the following configs in Lighttpd to get more details.

```
server.errorlog, accesslog.filename, debug.log-request-handling.


It is observed that more than 100 sock fd in the listening state and gets accepted in fdevent_accept_listenfd() from connection_accept() in the network_server_handle_fdevent().
```

All the connection request goes into reading state and falls into an error state after some time (From the Lighttpd debug logs).

At the time of issue, Inspect element(f12) from a web browser shows limited requests.

Log snippet for reference:

```
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1313) state at exit: 13 handle-req 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1236) state at enter 14 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 14 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 14 read 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1313) state at exit: 14 read 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1236) state at enter 15 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 15 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 15 read 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1313) state at exit: 15 read 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1236) state at enter 17 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 17 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 17 read 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1313) state at exit: 17 read 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1236) state at enter 18 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 18 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:30:13: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 18 read 
.
.
.
2020-10-23 09:31:02: (connections.c.1313) state at exit: 132 read 
2020-10-23 09:31:02: (connections.c.1236) state at enter 133 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:31:02: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 133 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:31:02: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 133 read 
2020-10-23 09:31:02: (connections.c.1313) state at exit: 133 read 
2020-10-23 09:31:02: (connections.c.1236) state at enter 134 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:31:02: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 134 req-start 
2020-10-23 09:31:02: (connections.c.1244) state for fd 134 read 
2020-10-23 09:31:02: (connections.c.1313) state at exit: 134 read
```

Packet capture shows continuous Client Hello, Server Hello and Change Cipher Spec packets between the browser and Lighttpd during this time. **The same issue is not happening with Lighttpd V1.4.45 + OpenSSL V1.1.1g**

Comment: lighttpd-1.4.54 was released May 2019 (17 months ago).  lighttpd-1.4.55 was released Jan 2020 (9 months ago).  Have you tried with lighttpd-1.4.55?  Have you tried with a different client?  Have you tried making a single request with curl or wget?

Comment: The issue is not consistent. But it occurs randomly. We have tried with the latest Lighttpd & OpenSSL also. Still, issue occurs in some cases.

Comment: "The issue is not consistent. But it occurs randomly. We have tried with the latest Lighttpd & OpenSSL also. Still, issue occurs in some cases."  Your problem report is vague and not reproducible.  Given your earlier statement "Packet capture shows continuous Client Hello, Server Hello and Change Cipher Spec packets between the browser and Lighttpd during this time.", I would suggest reviewing your cipher spec configuration in lighttpd.conf as well as ciphers supported by clients.

Comment: lighttpd 1.4.56 was released 29 Nov 2020 and lighttpd mod_openssl defaults to supporting TLSv1.2 and later, disabling earlier TLS versions.